# Foreign Key Error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have 2 tables (`Project1` and `Accounts`).

In `Projects1` table, I have 8 columns, 5 of which are assigned as the primary key.

In `Accounts` table I have 2 columns one of which is the primary key, and the other should be a foreign key that references to a column in `Project1` table.

- `Project1`: Id (Primary Key), Name (Primary Key), AccType(Primary Key),  AccNumber, DOC (Primary Key), DOM (Primary Key), Source, Status
- `Accounts` : Id (Primary Key), AccType (Foreign Key)

So here the `AccType` column in the `Accounts` table points to the `AccType` column in the `Project1` table.

`AccType` column in the `Project1` table is the PRIMARY KEY in the `Project1` table. The `AccType` column in the `Accounts` table is a FOREIGN KEY.

Query:

```
alter table Accounts  
add foreign key (AccType) references Project (AccType);
```

Here I am getting an error as:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'Project1' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK__Accounts__Accoun__2C3393D0'.

TIA
-Mithali

Comment: A foreign key must have the same number of columns as the primary key -- the composite key has 3.  Seems like you should have an `AccountType` table as well and both tables would reference it instead.

Comment: Got the Solution...

A table can have any number of Unique keys but only 1 primary key.

So i made the Project1 Table columns  Id , Name , DOC , DOM as 'Unique' and the column AccType as Primary Key.

And now finally i can make the column AccType as Foreign Key in Accounts Table.

Answer (score 0):

Dear you Can't Apply Primary key More Than One time
It will give You Error
Because Foreign Key Will Depend on Another table Primary key

Suppose

### TABLE 1 (USER)

### UID(Primary Key) | Name | Contact |

### 1                 Harsh  123456

### 2                 Guddu  789456

TABLE 2 (Email)

Here You Have to assign UID to apply Index key
Then in relation View Assign UID Of TABLE 1 (USER) To Connect UID of TABLE 2 (EMAIL)

---

EID(Primary Key) | UID(Foreign Key) | Email |

---

1                | 1 |               a@a.com

### 2                | 2 |               b@b.com

[Download Image From Below Link]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpn6J.png